# Error when trying to run resque-web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I get this error when running `resque-web`.  I've tried rebooting, reinstalling resque and vegas and recompiling ruby. This started happening after I ran out of hard drive space while a resque job was writing to a file. I made some free space but resque-web hasn't started since.

```
dan@ubuntu:~$ resque-web
[2012-09-10 22:34:02 -0400] Starting 'resque-web'...
/home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:35:in `initialize': No such file or directory -  (Errno::ENOENT)
  from /home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
  from /home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
  from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/vegas-0.1.11/lib/vegas/runner.rb:146:in `port_open?'
  from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/vegas-0.1.11/lib/vegas/runner.rb:160:in `check_for_running'
  from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/vegas-0.1.11/lib/vegas/runner.rb:108:in `start'
  from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/vegas-0.1.11/lib/vegas/runner.rb:77:in `initialize'
  from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/resque-1.22.0/bin/resque-web:13:in `new'
  from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/resque-1.22.0/bin/resque-web:13:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/resque-web:19:in `load'
  from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/resque-web:19:in `<main>'
  from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:13:in `eval'
  from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:13:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do `rm /home/dan/.vegas/resque_web/resque_web.url` and now it starts.